# import dlib ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib' in python IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, dlib, python-install

I have installed `dlib` using `Anaconda 3` prompt.
It has shown me that it got installed successfully. I checked through command `import dlib` it did not give me any error even I checked the version also it came up with `19.9.0`.

But when I open my program in IDLE and run the program its showing me error

```
import dlib ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'
```

Even from command prompt, I am getting same error.

What is the issue? I am using Python 3.6.

Installation process of `dlib` using `anaconda3`:

[image: Installation process of <code>dlib</code>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending [@Rohit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55570175/3129414):

As you have installed `dlib` in Anaconda, you need to run the program using Anaconda prompt.

By default, `IDLE` and `python` command in command prompt use Python that is installed system wide (which is `Python 3.6.0` in your case).

But to use `dlib` which is installed in Anaconda's virtual environment (`env_dlib`) you need to do:

1. Open Anaconda prompt.
2. Activate `env_dlib` environment: `activate env_dlib`
3. Run the Python file which uses `dlib` package: `python FILENAME`

Comment: yes I understood now .Before I was thinking both are installing system wide.I was not aware of virtual environment  of anaconda prompt. and I searched also so many but no where it was cleared. so many thanks to you.Sorry Could not give you feedback because I dont have 15 reputation. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have installed the package in different version of python and importing the package in other version of the python.

Package is installed. in virtual environment(`3.6.8`) and is being imported in standard system python (`3.6.0`).

So either you need to use this virtual environment for your application otherwise you will need to install the package into global system python.

Comment: yes I understood now .Before I was thinking both are installing system wide.I was not aware of virtual environment  of anaconda prompt. and I searched also so many but no where it was cleared. so many thanks to you.Sorry Could not give you feedback because I dont have 15 reputation. :)

Comment: glad to help @Tann